# Unable to loop through an object in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, django

I’m a bit lacking of knowledge in JS. I am accessing some data through an API and retrieving it as JSON. This data is getting into JS very nicely. But I do not really understand with which type object I’m dealing with. I cannot determine the length and also the other loop methods do not work. But I can access the object elements like an array with REValues[0] – first element.

```
function drawTable() {
        debugger;
        var REValues = {{ json|safe }};
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();

        data.addColumn('number', 'ID');
        data.addColumn('string', 'Stadt');
        data.addColumn('string', 'Bezirk');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Einkaufswert');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Fläche');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Miete');

        for (var REValue in REValues) {
            debugger;
        }
```

example of JSON responce:

```
{0: {'id': '114294281', 'creation': '2019-11-04T21:29:13.000+01:00', 'city': 'Dortmund', 'quarter': 'Huckarde', 'value': 92000, 'currency': 'EUR', 'livingSpace': 71, 'street': 'Urbanusstraße', 'houseNumber': 'x'}, 1: {'id': '109426963', 'creation': '2019-01-22T12:50:27.000+01:00', 'city': 'Dortmund', 'quarter': 'Huckarde', 'value': 129000, 'currency': 'EUR', 'livingSpace': 59, 'street': 'Roßbachstr.', 'houseNumber': '40 c'}, ...
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VBvx6.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per you json string you have an object and not an array.
The length of the attributes of the object can be calculated by

```
let objectLength = Object.keys(REValues).length;
```

And the object can be iterated using "for in "to read the values.

```
for (var REValue in REValues) {
    let val =REValues[REValue];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, `for…in` is used to iterate over the properties of an object (the object keys) rather than its values directly. Try to use `for…of` to iterate through the values instead!

Comment: If you can access revalues[0] it does not mean it's an array. "0" can be a key fir an object too. And as per your jain string this is the case. To get the length you can use  objectLength = Object.keys(revalues).length.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to loop through the object-

```
for (let key in yourobject) {
   if (yourobject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      console.log(yourobject[key]);
   }
}
```

Please pass in the object in place of **yourobject** and check the values.

Answer (score 0):

The data you are getting is an Object and the reason why data[0] is returning a value is because 0 is a property of the object data.

If you want to loop through object properties or get the length you can do this

```
//I am assuming that data holds your object
let keys = Object.keys( data )
```

Loop through this object properties

```
for (let k in keys) {
    let value = data[k]
    //now you can console log value or whatever you want to do 
    //(value can be any type of variable including another object)
}
```

If you wish to know how many properties does your object has (length)

```
keys.length()
```

I have NOT tested this code so it can have some typing errors. 
If you need more clarifications, please ask directly what are you are trying to archive, perhaps there is a better way.

Answer (score 0):

To oversimplify things...if it starts with a curly brace **{** you're likely looking at a JSON Object. If it starts with a square bracket **[** you're likely looking at a JSON array. For a detailed explanation, see [Objects vs. Arrays](https://dev.to/zac_heisey/objects-vs-arrays-2g0e).

However, any number of formatting errors in the JSON can invalidate it and make it difficult (or impossible) to manipulate. The example you provided *isn't valid JSON*. It may be helpful to start with a known good JSON Array that validates in a [JSON Formatter & Validator](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/).

Here's a simple example:

```
[
    { "manufacturer":"Ford", "models":[ "Fiesta", "Focus", "Mustang" ] },
    { "manufacturer":"BMW", "models":[ "320", "X3", "X5" ] },
    { "manufacturer":"Fiat", "models":[ "500", "Panda" ] }
]
```

Once you know the JSON coming back from the API is properly formatted, it will be easier to render it in your UI.

```js
// valid JSON
const myArray = [{
    "manufacturer": "Ford",
    "models": ["Fiesta", "Focus", "Mustang"]
  },
  {
    "manufacturer": "BMW",
    "models": ["320", "X3", "X5"]
  },
  {
    "manufacturer": "Fiat",
    "models": ["500", "Panda"]
  }
]

//create a new array containing only the manufacturers
const manufacturers = myArray.map(x => x.manufacturer);
//expected output => ["Ford","BMW","Fiat"]

// join the new array values in a comma separated string
console.log("This array contains models from " + manufacturers.join(", ") + ".");
```

Comment: Yes, I testet this JSON expression and it was not valid. But the Object looked very nice, that is why I left it like that. It comes from Python Dictionary, thats why the bad formating. Thank you for the JSON vs Objects Link.

Comment: Exactly. Your stated goal is to "determine the length and also the other loop methods do not work". Until your JSON is valid, those problems will persist. Is there a different, valid response from the API? If not, you may continue to have trouble.

Comment: Yes there is a different valid responce from the API, it is just too big for the usecase. Thant is why I am taking the needed information into a Dictionary, as the API call is on the Django backend. But now I can access the data in JS, so all good.

Comment: Excellent. If you have any trouble manipulating the JSON, you can always post one or two of the array objects as a sample. There are tons of useful [array methods](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_array_methods.asp).